# Multiple Akka Sources from one blocking iterator?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have an iterator which reads a binary records from an InputStream (blocking for new input), and produces elements which have one of three possible types, let's say types are T1, T2, T3.

What's the easiest way to produce 3 independent Akka Sources S1, S2 and S3 from that iterator based on the type of the message?

Each source will be consumed by a different library function, each requiring a Source as input.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use [`PartitionHub`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-partitionhub). For example:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("Terminator")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

sealed trait T
case class T1(id: Int) extends T
case class T2(id: Int) extends T
case class T3(id: Int) extends T

val partitioner: (Int, T) => Int = (num, t) =>
  t match {
    case t: T1 => 0
    case t: T2 => 1
    case t: T3 => 2
  }

val producer: Source[T, NotUsed] = Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.from(1).map {
  case i if i % 2 == 0 => T2(i)
  case i if i % 3 == 0 => T3(i)
  case i => T1(i)
})

val fromProducer: Source[T, NotUsed] =
  producer.toMat(PartitionHub.sink(
    partitioner,
    startAfterNrOfConsumers = 3, bufferSize = 256)
  )(Keep.right)
  .run()

fromProducer.runForeach(msg => println(s"consumer1: $msg"))
fromProducer.runForeach(msg => println(s"consumer2: $msg"))
fromProducer.runForeach(msg => println(s"consumer3: $msg"))
```

In the above example, `producer` is a `Source` that produces elements of type `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`. The `PartitionHub` creates a `Sink` that routes these elements to three consumers based on the type of the element. This `Sink` returns as the materialized value a `Source` (named `fromProducer` above), which itself can be materialized multiple times: the example materializes `fromProducer` three times and simply prints the elements. Each materialization can use whatever `Sink` you want.

Comment: This seems promising, the PartitionHub says it uses back-pressure instead of infinite buffering.Unfortunately the feature is classified "may change" in Akka docs.

Answer (score 0):

**Partition the Iterator**

You can do partitioning on the underlying `Iterator` before creating any akka `Source` values.

First dealing with the data:

```
sealed Trait Data

case class Foo() extends Data
case class Bar() extends Data
case class Baz() extends Data
```

The sealed trait can now be utilized for the partitioner functions:

```
val isAFoo : Data => Boolean = _ match {
  case _ : Foo => true
  case _       => false
}

val isABar : Data => Boolean = _ match {
  case _ : Bar => true
  case _       => false
}
```

Now the `Iterator` can be partitioned:

```
val sourceIterator : Iterator[Data] = ???

val (fooIterator, notFooIterator) = sourceIterator partition isAFoo

val (barIterator, bazIterator) = notFooIterator partition isABar
```

These Iterator values can feed different sources:

```
val fooSource : Source[Foo, _] = Source.fromIterator(() => fooIterator)

val barSource : Source[Bar, _] = Source.fromIterator(() => barIterator)

val bazSource : Source[Baz, _] = Source.fromIterator(() => bazIterator)
```

Comment: This is seemed like an ideal solution, but then I looked at the source of scala iterarator partition function. In worst case it seems to buffer all the original iterator values in memory (in a mutable lookahead buffer). I also wonder about the thread safety, doesn't akka run separate Sources in independent threads?